# ExtJS: Loading data into multiple combobox from a single json using nested model

Tags: json, extjs, combobox

I have the following scenario:

I have two comboboxes, with different root property.I want to load both comboboxes using same response.

Please provide some solution to accomplish this.

You can refer the fiddle for clear understanding.
            https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fti

I want to load first combobox with "RetrieveRegionComboList" and second combobox with "RetrieveLanguageComboList", by loading the json only once.

In this fiddle,Iam populating the combobox by making call to JSON twice using nested store in model. I want to achieve the same by using the single response to complete multiple request.

Thank You...

Comment: It is good to have a fiddle, especially for ExtJs, but please include the important part of the code in the question.

Comment: Sure, I ll keep this in mind... Sorry for the inconvinience...

Answer (score 1):

You can load the data in both combos like this :

First, you make an Ajax request, and in the success callback you decode the JSON and load the data into the stores.

Comment: Thank you for your response.. But I want to get the response in a store(master store), and want to create sub-stores(child stores) of it,which will be associated with respective combobox. Is it possible to achieve this in ExtJS??

Comment: Maybe, but it sounds like trying to go the hard way.